# Blender2Ogre - Execute python script in command line

Tags: python, command-line, blender

I would like to transform blender meshes into ogre meshes. I downloaded [this](https://bitbucket.org/alexeyknyshev/blender2ogre/src/3574db4e7dbbfa081fb2b73fddc90ba5148001eb/io_export_ogreDotScene.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)  add-on which is a python script that allows me to do it.
I already installed this extension in blender (user preferences - addons - Install) and works perfectly.
Now I would like to execute the same script in the command line so I can transform any mesh without opening the blender user interface.

Using cmd (I'm a windows user) I go to the folder where blender is installed and run the following command:

```
blender.exe --background --python ./2.76/scripts/addons/io_export_ogreDotScene.py box.blend
```

but nothing happens. I think it's because the script was written only to be used inside blender, not through the command line.

Is there a workaround to execute this script ? 
I'm not really good in python, so reading the script is not helping me at all.

I'll appreciate any help I can get form you guys !!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to decode the script and make it run from the command line. It converts a blender file sent as a parameter and converts it in a ogre mesh file.

If you need it, let me know.